# Javascript not reporting errors

Tags: javascript, debugging

So, I'm writing an application that has ~5k lines of javascript... and it's stopped reporting errors.  No firebug, IE triangle thing, nothing.  It just won't work if there's an error.  Anyone seen anything like this before? Debugging is somewhat... frustrating...

My best guess is too many layers of abstraction? But there aren't really that many.

Comment: If you're no longer getting errors, perhaps it's no longer getting loaded?

Comment: If you're getting no errors, the code is perfect :D Roll it out to all your sites immediately, and crack on with something else. When someone rings up to complain, ask them what error they're getting.

Comment: It's definitely loaded... (looked in firebug, and the parts preceding w/e error still run.)

Comment: Errors inside of exception handlers may be handled silently by the code and thus won't get reported in the debugger.  Chrome debugger has a setting to break on all exceptions (even those that are handled) if that's a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99% your script is not executing at all. You need manual trace, either with breakpoints, console.logs or alerts.

1% is that you have error handlers, who silence them. Look for suspicious `try { .. } catch () {}` and `window.onerror`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, try catch block in different file was preventing error messages. (where first file functions were called)

Answer (score 3):

**Something else is wrong. It's not simply the size of your javascript.** I'm running 70,000 lines of JavaScript in Chrome's debugger and FireFox 6's firebug and there are no debugging problems.

Look elsewhere. Is something not getting loaded? Do you need to clear cache and refresh? Try another browser (like Chrome) and see the results.

If it stopped reporting errors, its more likely those errors do not exist in your current revision, or that a block of code that you think is executing is actually never run. Set a breakpoint.

Comment: Same behavior in ff, firebug, chrome, ie (red flag...), multiple machines, cleared caches, etc.  It won't even report outright syntax errors (aldddert('hi')).  Just stops.

Comment: Ok what seems to be happening is a mootools try/catch is eating up the errors, which all originate inside of chained functions- looks like mootools is making them return some value instead of throwing the error.  I guess then this is a mootools issue...